# modelsim script for compile all

Tags: vhdl, simulation, simulator, modelsim

I have a modelsim project file (*.mpf), where it lists all the HDL files, and it provides a "compile_order" for each file. 
So, when I load the (.mpf) file, I can see that each one of my HDL files have a compoile_order number next to it. So far so good.

Now, on the GUI, I can run "compile all", and it will compile all my files in correct order, since the orders are already pre-determined.

I want to know that what is the tcl command line that is equivalent to the "compile all" in the GUI?

In other words, I want to be able to type a command and it compiles all the files, rather than I do "compile all" through the GUI.

Comment: If you can't find one, just write a .do script that compiles them one by one in the right order.

Comment: You can probably write a tcl script that parses the mpf. Find the `Project_File_` entries and compile them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the command `project`. You can use it in a "*.do" file this way :

```
project open MyProject.mpf
project compileall
```

For all others modelsim commands, you can look at the [Modelsim Command Reference Manual](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/136364-modelsim-me-10-4c-command-reference-manual-for-libero-soc-v11-7). `Project` command is described in page 220.